# Xforms event for clearing the field

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms

I just need help in xforms events. I've got boolean field - if the checkbox for the field is checked another field appears i.e Payment1 (I use relevant for this) to put amount in it - then I've got sum field. Problem is when I unchecked the field value of Payment1 is still count to Sum field. I would be grateful for event that clear value of the field Payment1 when the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have an `action` that will set the value for `Payment1` to an empty string.

In the example model below, if the element `bar` does not equal "checked" (the value of the select), then the element `foo` is set to an empty string.

```
    <xf:model>
        <xf:instance id="main">
            <data>
                <foo></foo>
                <bar></bar>
            </data>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:bind nodeset="instance('main')/foo" relevant="following-sibling::bar='checked'"/>
        <xf:action ev:event="xforms-refresh">
            <xf:action if="instance('main')/bar[not(.='checked')]">
                <xf:setvalue ref="instance('main')/foo" value="''"/>                       
            </xf:action>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:model>
```

Here's an example of the select (`bar`) and the input (`foo`):

```
<table>
    <row>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <xf:select ref="bar" selection="closed" appearance="full" incremental="true">
                <xf:item>
                  <xf:label>Click Me</xf:label>
                  <xf:value>checked</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
            </xf:select>
        </td>
    </row>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Input Foo: </td>
        <td>
            <xf:input incremental="true" ref="foo"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```